# Why am I getting Time Limit Exceeded error on O(n) time complexity code?

Tags: python

The question, https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/, asks:

Given an unsorted integer array nums, return the smallest missing positive integer.

You must implement an algorithm that runs in O(n) time and uses constant extra space.

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [1,2,0]
Output: 3
Example 2:

Input: nums = [3,4,-1,1]
Output: 2
Example 3:

Input: nums = [7,8,9,11,12]
Output: 1
 

Constraints:

1 <= nums.length <= 5 * 10**5
-2**31 <= nums[i] <= 2**31 - 1
```

Thus my code satisfies this:

```
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        nums=sorted(list(filter(lambda x: x>=0, nums)))
        nums= list(dict.fromkeys(nums))
        if 1 not in nums: return 1
        x=nums[0]
        for num in nums:
            if nums.index(num) != 0:
                dif = num - x
                if dif!=1:
                    return x + 1
                x=num
        return num+1
```

Glad for anyone to offer help.

Comment: That is not O(n). You sorted!

Comment: And you're calling `index` over and over!

Comment: And you're not using constant extra space like they told you to, either!

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thank you, i thought sort was o(n)

Comment: thank you @user2357112supportsMonica, why should index function be a problem? it is only o(1) time

Comment: `list.index` is O(n). You are calling it worst-case n times. So this algorithm becomes O(n**2)

Comment: thank you thank you. I will refine the code

Comment: Hint: they didn't explicitly say you can overwrite the input (and they really should have said so), but you're going to need to use the input list as scratch space to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments described, `sorted()` doesn't take linear time. `sorted()` also creates a new list, so your solution also violates the `O(1)` memory constraint.

Here's a linear-time, constant-space solution. The problem asks for two things (for simplicity, let `n = len(nums)`):

1. a data structure that can in `O(1)` time, determine whether a positive integer in the interval `[1, n]` is in `nums`. (We have `n` numbers to check, and the runtime of our algorithm has to be linear.) For this problem, our strategy is to create a table such that for every integer `i` between 1 and `n`, if `i` is in nums, then `nums[i - 1] = i`. (The answer has to be positive, and the answer can't be greater than `n + 1` -- the only way for the answer to be `n + 1` is if `nums` contains every integer in the interval `[1, n]`).
2. a procedure to generate the data structure in-place to meet the memory constraint.

Here's a solution that does this.

```py
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        # Match elements to their indicies.
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            num_to_place = num
            while num_to_place > 0 and num_to_place <= len(nums) and num_to_place != nums[num_to_place - 1]:
                next_num_to_place = nums[num_to_place - 1]
                nums[num_to_place - 1] = num_to_place
                num_to_place = next_num_to_place
        
        # Find smallest number that doesn't exist in the array.
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] != i + 1:
                return i + 1
        
        return len(nums) + 1
```

Both `for` loops takes linear time. The reasoning for the second is obvious, but the time analysis of the first is a bit more subtle:

Notice that the `while` loop contains this condition: `num_to_place != nums[num_to_place - 1]`. For each iteration of this `while` loop, the number of values that meet this condition decreases by 1. So, this `while` loop can only execute at most `n` times across all iterations, meaning the first `for` loop takes `O(n)` time.

Comment: Excellent answer. This is probably just a matter of taste, but personally I would find the number-swapping easier to parse without the temporary variable. It would probably require shortening the variable to fit comfortably on one line, something like `num, nums[num - 1] = nums[num - 1], num`

Comment: Good suggestion! Normally I'd agree with you, but the location of `nums[num - 1]` depends on `num`, which we assign to in the same line. In fact, the suggested replacement you've given doesn't work, because `num` gets assigned to first, causing `nums[num - 1]` on the LHS to refer to a different memory location. You can make tuple assignment work here by swapping the LHS and RHS, but it's fragile, so I'd prefer in this case to avoid it altogether.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. I guess I've never swapped variables that involved a calculated index like that. Thank you for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

```
# O(n) time and O(1) space
class Solution:
def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    index = 0
    while index < len(nums):
        if nums[index] > 0 and nums[index] - 1 < len(nums) and nums[index] != nums[nums[index] - 1]:
            nums[nums[index]-1], nums[index] = nums[index], nums[nums[index] - 1]
        else:
            index += 1
    
    for i, integer in enumerate(nums):
        if integer != i + 1:
            return i + 1
    return len(nums) + 1
```